# How do I remove flat-remix from an installed system using a live system?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, package-management, icon-themes, live-environment

I've installed flat-remix and restarted my device, but now I can't log in because my language was set to Persian, and now I can't change it to English.

I can edit my files from live Ubuntu. How can I change my language or uninstall flat-remix from my device, in a live Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/deleting-flat-remix/19438

According to the [github page](https://github.com/daniruiz/Flat-Remix-GTK), to install ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniruiz/flat-remix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flat-remix-gtk
```

`sudo apt-get remove flat-remix-gtk` should work.